Error when accesing to API with OAuth2 or Devportal
I'm trying to access an API and it works correct if I use BASIC Auth or if I do the request from Try Out in Publisher, but when trying to access with OAuth2 or even Devportal using the subscription I get this error of response:
{   "code": "900900",   "message": "Unclassified Authentication Failure",   "description": "Unclassified Authentication Failure" }

And this in wso2carbon:

ID: [-1234] [oauth2] [2024-10-25 08:40:34,693] ERROR
{org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.jwks.JwksEndpoint} - Error
while generating the keyset for tenant domain: carbon.super
java.lang.ClassCastException: class sun.security.ec.ECPublicKeyImpl
cannot be cast to class java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey
(sun.security.ec.ECPublicKeyImpl is in module jdk.crypto.ec of loader
'platform'; java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey is in module
java.base of loader 'bootstrap')  at
org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.jwks.JwksEndpoint.getJWK(JwksEndpoint.java:160)
at TID: [] [] [2024-10-25 08:40:34,695] ERROR
{org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.jwt.JWTValidatorImpl} - Error while
parsing JWKS information java.text.ParseException: Invalid JSON:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING
at line 1 column 1 path $     at
com.nimbusds.jose.util.JSONObjectUtils.parse(JSONObjectUtils.java:130)
at
com.nimbusds.jose.util.JSONObjectUtils.parse(JSONObjectUtils.java:83)
at com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.JWKSet.parse(JWKSet.java:405)

Any ideas why this happening? Maybe is the certificate I'm using for signing the JWT?
I have change it for the default cert.
I have tried with another environment I have set up, but the same result.

I would check the next things:

Public Key Type Mismatch.

Error ClassCastException you're seeing indicates that WSO2 is attempting to cast an EC (Elliptic Curve) public key to an RSA public key. If your JWT is signed with an EC key, but WSO2 expects an RSA key, it will throw this error.
Solution: Check the certificate used to sign your JWT. Ensure that both the client and WSO2 are using compatible key types (either both RSA or both EC). WSO2 typically works well with RSA certificates by default.

Invalid JSON Parsing.

The parsing error indicates an issue with the JWKS (JSON Web Key Set) response, possibly due to an incorrectly formatted JWKS JSON. Sometimes, this happens if WSO2 receives unexpected data, like a plain string instead of a JSON object.
Solution: Verify that the JWKS endpoint returns a valid JSON structure. Also, ensure that the endpoint URL is correctly configured in WSO2.

Certificate Configuration.

Since you mentioned changing to the default certificate, it’s possible there’s a mismatch in the dev environment configuration or the default cert doesn’t align with the issuer of your JWT.
Solution: Try regenerating or reimporting the certificate used for signing the JWT and configure it explicitly in WSO2 to confirm alignment.

Testing with JWKS.

If possible, test the JWKS response independently to confirm that it contains the expected keys in JSON format (and check if they are RSA or EC). Additionally, check the certificate validation setup on your development environment for alignment.
If these solutions don’t resolve the issue, double-check your WSO2 OAuth2 and JWT validator configurations, as specific configurations may vary across environments.

Hello, thanks Alex for your response, im a bit confused becase what i have changed is the keystore internal certificate to match the new hostname, that certificate it is EC algorith but as far as i know the certificate that signs the JWT is the one configure in keystore primary, that one is the default wso2carbon with RSA algorithm. Am i missing something? Do i need to also configure the new certificate in the keystore primary to match de tls one? I have tried that and i get the EC casting error to RSA, but i can not change to EC to RSA... thanks
